# TableView row needs to de deleted twice before isn't removes form the UI?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, delete-row

I have got to the point where I can add cells that all have different `labels`. But, when the row is swiped to be deleted it will only delete the text associated with the cell and not the cell itself. I've tried to add `SavedMessages.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` inside the `if` statement but every time the app tries to delete the row, the app crashes.

Here is the code:-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
   if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
      let delete: NSFetchRequest<Messages> = Messages.fetchRequest()
      do { 
          var deleteMessage = try
          PersistenceServce.context.fetch(delete)
          PersistenceServce.context.delete(messages.remove(at: indexPath.row))
          PersistenceServce.saveContext()
          self.messages = deleteMessage
          SavedMessages.reloadData()
      } catch {}
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is error message

Comment: First you need to remove item from array then use `SavedMessages.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` to delete cell from UI

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya the fetched CoreData should be deleting the item in the array that was stored. That data deletes just fine but, once the cell was deleted it leaves a blank cell.

Comment: Check your data properly deleted or not. (Check the count). and also put break point in cell for row there might be returning empty Cell like UITableViewCell() or whatever your class if you have if - else condition in cellForRow method

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I know the data is being deleted properly because I added a print(“DELETED ”) in the savedData() inside the CoreData App Delegate. I’ll try to add something similar to see if the table view is returning an empty cell like you said. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I just saw your previous comment on the error message. It’s a 0_pthread__kill.

Comment: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: Simply remove object from array first and then after remove from tableview like this  

self.arrMessage.remove(element: objectMessage)
self.tblMessage.deleteRows(at: [cellIndex!], with: .fade)

Comment: What crash do you get when you use `SavedMessages.deleteRows`.  While the data may be getting deleted are you sure that whatever is used as the data for the table view is also being updated.

Comment: @ravi.p Thank you! Your suggestion works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not using

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

I created an example where removing data as well as the cell is getting removed perfectly fine.

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
     section: Int) -> Int 
     {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {

        data.remove(at: indexPath.row) //removing the value from data source.

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.removeFromSuperview() //removing the cell

        tableView.reloadData() //reloading Table data.
    }
}
```